# How to find lexically smallest string in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find lexically smallest string in an index of elasticsearch. The [Min Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html#_script?q=min) works only for numeric values. Is there any other aggregation that solves this problem ?

Comment: Are you looking at a single field, a specific set of fields or any field in your documents?

Comment: @Val at a single field.